# Strange sudo message at startup

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu, sudo

I have Kubuntu 10.04 LTS, and since I installed it on my computer, I get a password prompt after login. I can use the computer without any problems if I don't enter the password there, so I usually just cancel it. But now I decided to track down what it is actually.

```
peet@peti-linux:~$ ps -ef | grep sudo
root      1743  1732  0 17:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/sudo -H -S -p passprompt -- sh -c dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/volume_uuid_a1d03501_1432_455d_b80c_5cca7a315221 org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.Volume.Mount string:/boot string: array:string:
peet      2028  1846  0 17:53 pts/1    00:00:00 grep sudo
peet@peti-linux:~$ ps -f --pid=1732
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
peet      1732  1608  0 17:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kdesu -d --noignorebutton --comment Please enter your password to use this device -c dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesk
peet@peti-linux:~$ ps -f --pid=1608
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
peet      1608     1  0 17:47 ?        00:00:00 kdeinit4: kded4 [kdeinit]
peet@peti-linux:~$ grep a1d03501 /etc/fstab
UUID=a1d03501-1432-455d-b80c-5cca7a315221 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

So I found that it wants to do something with the device my /boot directory is mounted to. Just to clarify: I have /boot mounted on a pendrive, and / on an external hard drive (it is because my computer doesn't boot from e-sata for some reason). And I can see /boot without any problems, and everything else seems to work.

My question is, what does KDE want with that pendrive, why does it pop up that sudo dialog, and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add the 'user' option in your /etc/fstab. See 'man mount' for more info.